# Logic: on the Axiom of Choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $X,Y,Z$ be infinite sets and $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a surjective function. How can I prove that if $|Y| \le |Z|$ and for every $y \in Y$ is $|f^{-1}(y)| \le |Z|$, the following inequality holds: $|X| \le |Z|$ ?

Comment: What are your ideas? Are you allowed to use cardinal arithmetic or do you need to find an injective map $X \to Z$?

Comment: I think that the point is to find such an injective map (using axiom of choice or an equivalent formulation). It's actually an old exam question i'm struggling with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are allowed to use cardinal arithmetic, then the following calculate is immediate:

$$|X|=\left|\bigcup_{y\in Y}f^{-1}(y)\right|=\sum_{y\in Y}|f^{-1}(y)|=|Y|\cdot\sup\{|f^{-1}(y)|\mid y\in Y\}\leq|Z|\cdot|Z|=|Z|$$

If you want to actually find an injection from $X$ to $Z$, you might want to use the fact that you have a bijection between $Z$ and $Y\times Z$. Now for every $y\in Y$ choose an injection from $f^{-1}(y)$ into $Z$ and finish the proof in the obvious way.

Comment: To avoid unnecessary difficulties, I would replace the third equality with an inequality.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Using $X \cong \displaystyle\coprod_{y \in Y} f^{-1}(y)$, can you embed it in something that you know (by AC) has cardinality $|Z|$? You may want to think about the cardinality of $\displaystyle \coprod_{s \in S} T$ for arbitrary sets $S$ and $T$.